# Character masking - column in sql (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

i am using oracle sql.
i would like to character mask the output data of a query like below

Original

ANDREI/TOKAREV MR

MIRANOVA/OLGA MS

Output Should be

AND.../TOK... MR

MIR.../OLG... MS

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to split that string into 3 parts (that's what `regexp_substr` does), and then leave the first 3 characters intact, while the rest is represented by three dots. Concatenate these pieces into the final result.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'ANDREI/TOKAREV MR' from dual union all
  3     select 'MIRANOVA/OLGA MS' from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select col, substr(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1), 1, 3) || '...' ||'/'||
  6              substr(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2), 1, 3) || '...' ||' '||
  7              regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) as result
  8  from test;

COL               RESULT
----------------- ----------------------------------------
ANDREI/TOKAREV MR AND.../TOK... MR
MIRANOVA/OLGA MS  MIR.../OLG... MS

SQL>
```